# Неверное отображение сайта

Tags: html, css, хостинг

Я выложил свой сайт на хостинге, но отображается он не так, как надо. Вот ссылка на то, что отображается: http://bananashop-top.ru.xsph.ru/# ;
Вот как должно отображаться: [![Магазин][1]][1]. Проблема с блоком с названием "Магазин".

Вот код:

HTML:

```
<div class="shop" tabindex="0">
                    <h2>Магазин</h2>
                    <div class="shop-card">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h2>Магазин</h2>
                            <p>Это магазин. Здесь вы можете выбрать бананы для покупки</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="button">
                            <a href="#">Магазин</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* shop */
main .shop {
    margin: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffeb3b;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px -3px;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

main .shop h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

main .shop:hover {
    background-color: #fdd835;
}

main .shop:focus .shop-card {
    opacity: 1;
}

main .shop:focus h2 {
    display: none;
}

main .shop .shop-card {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #fff9c4, #ffee58);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px -4px #000;
}

main .shop .text p {
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

main .shop .button {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

main .shop .button a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #29b6f6;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

main .shop .button a:hover {
    background-color: #039be5;
}
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJCq8.png[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приложите более подробное описание "проблемы". и желательно два скриншота - до и после. сайт по ссылке у меня выглядит при зуме 80 % так же как и на скриншоте, непонятно в чем проблема

Comment: Дело в том, что при загрузке сайта с компьютера всё выглядит нормально, но при просмотре сайта с хостинга это выглядит как на скриншоте ( я его добавил )

Comment: возможно, дело в кеше (так как у меня нормально выглядит), и обновлённые стили для сайта не подгрузились. попробуйте поменять название css файла и перезалить на хостинг